# Javascript amount of transfered data on page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, data-transfer

I am looking for a programmatic way to display how much data was transferred when accessing a website - for example as seen in Google Chrome's DevTools:

[image]

Is there a browser API to read this information from?

I was looking and searching everywhere, but it seems it cannot be done? Does anyone have any experience with this? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have a look at the Performance API:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/performance and in particular the `transferSize` prop :  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceResourceTiming/transferSize

Comment: @Gabriel thanks! Thats exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Then allow me to re-post as an Answer, for you to accept ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the Performance API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/performance

and in particular the `transferSize` prop : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceResourceTiming/transferSize